# Why can't I import data into an existing table?

Tags: sql-server

I have an empty table into which I am trying to import data from a flat file.  The only option I seem to have is to create the table, which isn't needed.  Why can't I select the other options?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the screen before the one on your screenshot click where the destination table name is to select an existing table.

[image]

Comment: Yup! That's what I had done. Still won't let me select anything but Create New

Comment: So do you mean you have table showing in the list but it won't let you select them? Do you get an error? Might be that you do not have insert permission on the tables.